# Iterating over pyspark df becomes slower every iteration

Tags: python, pyspark

If I have a spark DF, it is my understanding that the DF is not really materialized until it is persisted or something similar, and that it is theoretically "just an explain plan" until said thing happens. For example, if I have `df` and remove some rows from it, until the DF needs to be materialized, it really just is `df - subset1`, and if i remove some more rows, it is `df - subset1 - subset2`.

I have a use case in which this is done in a `for` loop, and every iteration was consistently at least doubling in time of execution. After some research, doing this at the end of every loop, fixed the problem:

```
data = data.rdd.toDF(schema)
```

In my case, that line, takes about 1 minute and `data` is originally 10MM rows with 30 string columns and has a decrease of 1MM rows every iteration.

1. Am I understanding this correctly?
2. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: for #2, we can help you better if we understand the use case you're doing at a high level. re: understanding, you should look into the lineage your use case creates. if you're chaining your operations - iter-1 takes, lets say, 2 mins; the chained iter-2 first has to execute iter-1 again (lazy eval) and then execute iter-2, so 2+~2 mins; and this goes on.